# Nested if statements in java not reading second if statement

Tags: java, nested

I had a quick question about nested if statements. My code needs to check that the user inputs is a valid double and that it is not a zero and then outputs the reciprocal. I can get it to check that the input is an valid input and output the reciprocal but when I try to enter in a zero it terminates the program. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Reciprocal {

    public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter in a non-zero number");
    if (stdin.hasNextDouble()) {
        double number = stdin.nextDouble();
        if (number != 0) {
            System.out.println("The Reciprocal is " + 1 / number);
        }
        System.out.println("The Not Reciprocal is");            
    } else {
      System.out.println(" The input you entered is invalid, please try again.");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with a zero value you try to get "1 / number" so you get a division by zero exception and I think this is why your program stops.

Comment: I get the message `The Reciprocal is Infinity`. What do you expect?

Comment: I need the program to print out that the input you entered is invalid, please try again. I can get either the !=0 line to work or the hasNextDouble to work, but I can't get both of them to work

Answer (score 1):

Remove your second `System.out.println("The Reciprocal is "+ 1/number);` or move it into the `if`-block.

Comment: I removed the 2nd SOP and it's still terminating. Not sure what's going on. At first I wasn't sure if I had the brackets placed correctly, but I've tried just about everything that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `1/number` even if number is `0` secondly your else part should be inside the if block if user enters `0` it should be going to the else part according to your message.

*So it should be like this,*

```
if(stdin.hasNextDouble()){
    double number = stdin.nextDouble();

    if(number !=0){
       System.out.println("The Reciprocal is "+ 1/number);
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("Wrong Input!");//If input is 0
    }
}else {
   System.out.println("Invalid Input");//If input is not double value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 0 error.

```
System.out.println("The Reciprocal is "+ 1/number);
```

That line is done twice if number is not 0, and once if it is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mistake. This line:

`System.out.println("The Reciprocal is "+ 1/number);`

is being executed even when `number == 0` since you have it out of if sentence.

Comment: I removed the second SOP from the code and it's still terminating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no else on the inner if, so it checks that it is not 0, doesnt execute the code within the if, then goes to the `System.out.println("The Reciprocal is "+ 1/number);` line that is after the if statement.

What is the point of your if statement if all it does is allow that line to be executed twice

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code

```
double number = stdin.nextDouble();
if (number != 0) {
    System.out.println("The Reciprocal is " + 1 / number);
  }
System.out.println("The Reciprocal is " + 1 / number); //*
```

line I put * will execute always whether or not `if` condition satisfy.

You can change your code to following.

```
double number = stdin.nextDouble();
if (number != 0) {
   System.out.println("The Reciprocal is " + 1 / number);
}else {
   System.out.println("The Not Reciprocal is");
}
```

Comment: I tried that, I removed one of the brackets following SOP("The Reciprocal is" + 1/number); this works to check if it's a zero or not but now the code does not work if I enter in a string instead of a double.

Comment: if(stdin.hasNextDouble())
  {
   
   double number = stdin.nextDouble();

   if(number !=0)
   {

   
   System.out.println("The Reciprocal is "+ 1/number);
  

  }
  
  
  else
  {
   System.out.println(" The input you entered is invalid, please try again.");
   
  }}}}